# Android device not recognized in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb

I know this is a rather common question, but I tried all the solutions I found on other post and they didn't do the trick for me.

Basically, I have a Samsung Galaxy S, that worked fine with eclipse, so I was able to debug applications directly on my smartphone.

I tried 2 days ago since a lot of time, and the device is not recognized by the system, even `lsusb` can't find it.

I tried with a friend's smartphone, from a different brand, and it worked fine, so i guess it's something related to my smartphone, but I can't figure it out.

Debug is enabled on the phone, any other idea? My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: I ended up using ADB WIFI after my cable connector stopped working. The only downside is that both the computer and the device need to be connected to the same network, other than that it works just fine. MAYBE, this helps you, that's why its not an answer and just a comment.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have some links pointing to it?

Comment: I believe you need to be rooted for this (more than likely), the app is free and has no ads that I'm aware of, here's a link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You have to deleate the data where the debugs and the runs are stored
I don't know where it was because i had this problem last year.

But whene i deleted the data it works fine again

**Edit :**

Found it

```
C:\Users\UserName\.android
```

delete

**debug.keystore**

Comment: Did you close eclips befor deleting??

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that is not recognized even by `lsusb`

Answer (score 0):

I guess Samsung Galaxy S drivers are not installed properly. Install pdanet software in your workstation while installing it will ask connect your mobile with usb then it will install drivers automatically. I think it will work for you. try this..[From this link you can find the software](http://download.cnet.com/PdaNet/3000-10440_4-75059341.html)